# Run specific configurations

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, emf, epsilon

Hello i am facing a problem with the eclipse run configurations. I searched to find a simple example of how to solve my problem but i havent found any.

Well, my program has a file that it calls smth.model and if i want to run this model file to create an HTML file containing all the information of the model i needed to create a specific configuration that i am pointing to the specific model file and to specific HTML template (egl). Everything is working fine.

What i want now is lets say a user has never use the eclipse environment i want him to right click to his model file and there to have an option to run a specific configuration which i will call it for example "HTML run". When i right click to the model file i have the option Run as which directs me to the run configuration wizard. I dont want that i want the user when he choose the run as to show him my configuration rather the wizard.

Is it possible?Is there an example that will help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try something on Right Click>>Open With

Comment: You may consider to use the "External Tools" and add your custom configuration to that.

Answer (score 0):

Find any plug-ins for your specific need on Eclipse marketplace ( Help>>Eclipse Marketplace)

Comment: Thanks for your response but i dont think it will help. What i am looking actually is to write a script to execute the configurations

Comment: That will be much better.

Comment: do you know any example that can help me?

Comment: Need to find that on eclipse marketplace... you know too much work too little time.

Answer (score 0):

Your menu command can run EGL programatically, that is execute the EGL template that generates the HTML from Java. This example can guide you:
[Epsilon Standalone](http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/examples/index.php?example=org.eclipse.epsilon.examples.standalone).